# Possible thread unsafe operation on std::map

Tags: c++, stl, thread-safety

The STL does not guarantee thread safety of its collections. But I am wonder whether the following code actually works.

One thread calls a non-const operation on the map m by calling the [] operator, but with a key that already exists on the map. As far as I can tell, this just calls find() and returns a reference to the iterator in gcc. The other thread holds const iterators to m at the same time.

The question is: will the asserts ever fail?

```
void doBracket(std::map<int, int>& m) {
  const auto&  val = m[0];
  std::cerr << val << std::endl;
}


void doIter(const std::map<int, int>& m){
  auto zeroIter = m.find(0);
  auto oneIter = m.find(1);
  auto twoIter = m.find(2);
  assert(zeroIter->second == 0);
  assert(oneIter->second == 1);
  assert(twoIter->second == 2);
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, int> m = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
  std::thread mutateThread {doBracket, std::ref(m)};
  std::thread constThread  {doIter, std:ref(m)};
  mutateThread.join();
  constThread.join();
}
```

Here is what stl_map does:

```
   operator[](const key_type& __k)
      {
        // concept requirements
        __glibcxx_function_requires(_DefaultConstructibleConcept<mapped_type>)

        iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
        // __i->first is greater than or equivalent to __k.
        if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
                 //handle this case

        return (*__i).second;
      }
```

Comment: Your code is not thread safe, whatsoever. Every ìterator altering operation has to be guarded by a  mutex.

Comment: Dieter: I understand that the standard says that. I am more interested in the actual implementation.  I updated with stl_map code which seems to imply that the code is actually thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/, it says about map::operator[]:

> **Iterator validity**
>
> No changes.
>
> **Data races**
>
> The container is accessed, and potentially modified.
> The function accesses an element and returns a reference that can be used to modify its mapped value. Concurrently accessing other elements is safe.
> If the function inserts a new element, concurrently iterating ranges in the container is not safe.

The only potentially unsafe situation according to this is "concurrently iterating ranges in the container, if the function inserts a new element". Since you are not doing any inserting, the conclusion must be that your code is safe.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have identified a place where you can go beyond the standard by knowing the implementation.  However, this approach has no advantage over the guaranteed-safe approach of using `find()` instead of `operator[]()`.

Sidebar: I personally find `std::map::operator[]()` to be almost useless.  I always end up wanting to use `find()`, `insert()`, or something else.

Comment: Thanks, John. I am actually debugging a situation where we have exactly this situation (with two threads, one iterating over a map and one doing a bracket operator on a known key).  The map appears to be corrupted and the  thought was maybe the non-const bracket operator causes the corruption. Looking at the implementation, it doesn't appear to be the case. I agree that the code should be changed to use find(). But I want to rule out this possibility.

Comment: Well, you should change the code to use `find()` and see if it fixes the problem.  You should also consider using tools like valgrind and helgrind to perhaps speed up  your troubleshooting, if you're on Linux.